# How to group text in a UITextField like in the Google Maps application where "Current Location" is grouped?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uitextfield

I have a UITextField similar to the one in Google Maps' direction view. I want to be able to group the text text "Current Location" so that the user can remove it by pressing just a backspace. Is there any public API for doing so?

Regards,
Ashish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The control that looks kind of like a UITextField in the Google Maps direction view is not a UITextField, it is a custom control.   Or, it is not a UITextField *alone*, but a clever overlaying of UILabels, UIImages, etc. on top of a UITextField.    You don't get all that functionality with the vanilla UITextField.